# Decompose the delta function into the spatial and temporal part

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, conservation-laws, dirac-delta-distributions

I'm considering this scalar decay process:
[image]
where we write the four-momenta
$$
p_1 = (E_{p_1},  p),\qquad p_2 = (E_{p_2},  -p),\qquad P = p_1+p_2 = (\mu,0)
$$

The Dirac delta function could be written as $\delta^4(P-p_1-p_2)$.

I'm now trying to decompose the delta function into the spatial and temporal parts. I think the temporal part is straightforward: $\delta[\mu-(E_{p_1}+E_{p_2})]$. I was told the spatial part is $\delta^3(p_1+p_2)$, but I got confused about why that's the case. Shouldn't that be $\delta^3(0)$, because the spacial components are summed to be $0$?

Comment: The Dirac delta function imposes the condition that $P=p_1+p_2$. Therefore, in its argument you need to have the spatial parts of all the four-momenta prior to imposing the condition.

Comment: @flippiefanus Thanks for the comment! But if we only include the spatial part of $P-p_1-p_2$, shouldn't we still get $0-p-(-p) = 0$?

Comment: No, because those quantities do not taken on those value when they are sitting in the argument of the Dirac delta. It is only when the constraint that is imposed by the Dirac delta function is evaluated (namely that its argument becomes zero) that the quantities take on those values.

Comment: @flippiefanus Thank you!! Sorry I think I might still be a bit confused about how to do this. $p_1$ and $p_2$ are four-momenta, if we only include the spatial part in $\delta^3$, should that be $\delta^3(2p)$ instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was told the spatial part is $\delta^3(p_1+p_2)$, but I got confused about why that's the case. Shouldn't that be $\delta^3(0)$, because the spacial components are summed to be $0$?

No, it shouldn't be $\delta^3(0)$. The term $\delta^3(\vec p_1 + \vec p_2)$ imposes the condition that $\vec p_1 + \vec p_2 = 0$. A term like $\delta^3(0)$ is an "infinite" constant and does not impose any condition on anything.

---

> ...we write the four-momenta
> $$
> p_1 = (E_{p_1},  p),\qquad p_2 = (E_{p_2},  -p),\qquad P = p_1+p_2 = (\mu,0)
> $$

No, you should write:
$$
p_1 = (E_{p_1},  \vec p_1),\qquad p_2 = (E_{p_2},  \vec p_2),\qquad P = p_1+p_2 = (\mu,0)
$$
since you haven't imposed any conditions yet. This is what the delta function does for you.

---

The condition:
$$
p_1 + p_2 = P
$$
says, in component form:
$$
(E_{p_1}+E_{p_2}, \vec p_1 + \vec p_2) = (\mu , 0)\;.
$$

The temporal part of the above is:
$$
E_{p_1}+E_{p_2} = \mu\;,
$$
which can also be written as
$$
E_{p_1}+E_{p_2} - \mu = 0
$$

The spatial part is:
$$
\vec p_1 + \vec p_2 = 0\;,
$$

These conditions are imposed by just sticking the things that should be zero into the arguments of delta functions:
$$
\delta(E_{p_1}+E_{p_2} - \mu )
$$
and
$$
\delta(\vec p_1 + \vec p_2)
$$

Comment: Thanks so much, this is really helpful! Is it right to say the delta functions ensured the 4-momenta (and energies) are conserved at each vertex, so that $p_1+p_2 = P$?

Comment: Yes, that seems fine to say. I would probably use the present tense rather than the past tense, but it doesn't really matter.